# How to separate value $_GET

Tags: php, get

I have a problem with getting one value.
I'm calling my script with:

```
xxx.php?action=activate&timestamp=1415550311&gate=smscz&pricing=czchest1
&sum=29.00&currency=czk&days=0&identifiers%5Bglobal%5D%5Btext%5D=NomisCZ&key=czchest1`

$action = $_GET['action'];
$pricing = $_GET['pricing'];
```

etc.

but I have problem with getting value `&identifiers`. I need **only value NomisCZ from this** **`&identifiers%5Bglobal%5D%5Btext%5D=NomisCZ`.**

Comment: It's an array. What happened *when* you tried to access its value?

Comment: Nothing, because I don't know how can I get only value NomisCZ.

Comment: [`print_r($_GET)`](http://php.net/print_r) will tell you about the structure, the manual about [accessing arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your request, url decoded

```
identifiers[global][text]=NomisCZ&key=czchest1
```

To access NomisCZ use this

```
$_GET['identifiers']['global']['text'];
```

Comment: Thank you :) Works great urldecode($_GET['identifiers']['global']['text']);